# VaR calculation: Error in if(class(x) == "numeric") : the condition has length < 1

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

in the course of my bachelor thesis I have to perform a value at risk calculation based on a vector. The vector is available to me in the form of an Excel file, which I have already imported into R. For the calculation and subsequent graphical representation I use the packages mosaic, PerformanceAnalytics and ggplot2.

If I now select the vector as the data basis, I get the error message "Error in if (class(x) == "numeric") : the condition has length <1

What do I have to change to display the VaR of the vector? Unfortunately I am a complete beginner in R and try to help myself with YouTube videos, so I apologize for obvious errors that I do not recognize.

[image]

Here is an image of my code. I know I haven't tried a lot but im completely lost and I hope one of you guys can give me a short instruction how to do it.

Comment: Please copy and paste your code along with an example of your data, perhaps by using the output of `dput()`. Taking a screenshot does not help us.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So the code I used is VaR(profitlossvektor, p = 0.99, method = "historical") There is not much more I've done, because this is the way you use the command "VaR". My problem is, that the "profitlossvektor" seems to have a wrong data type or something so the command "VaR" can't work with it. The vector contains two rows with dates and the related profit or loss in €. By using dput(), the system only gives me a list of all dates and € amounts. (3.619 in total). I hope this describes my problem a little bit better..

Comment: It doesn't. Please edit your question and copy/paste the output of `dput()` so that your problem is reproducible.